# Flutter - form field error message - display somewhere other than below related widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter form and widgets that are using the 'validator' method. Is it possible to show validator error message text at a location other than directly below the widget?

For example,  I am trying to validate two related widgets, and using GlobalKey values linked to each widget to allow access to data.

The error message that I want to show is longer than can be displayed under the widget itself.  Can I somehow have a text field set at the bottom of the form used to display the error message?